# Does the first fundamental form = identity imply that a surface is developable?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

If the first fundamental form of a surface is $\mathbb{I}$, then the Gauss-Peterson-Mainardi-Codazzi equations reduce to: $LN - M^2 = 0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial V} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial U} = 0$, and $\frac{\partial M}{\partial V} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial U} = 0$, where $L, M, N$ are the coefficients of the second fundamental form. $LN - M^2$ is also the Gaussian Curvature $K$, so the surface has $K = 0$ and is developable. However, I understood that the second fundamental form for any surface with Gauss curvature $0$ also has $M = N = 0$. To my eye, these conditions on $M$ and $N$ do not emerge from the GPMC equations. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: If you assume there are no planar points, then, yes, you can prove the surface is a developable ruled surface. Since there are no planar points, you can choose coordinates so that $L\ne 0$ and $M=N=0$. It does not follow for arbitrary parameterizations.

Comment: I thought the second fundamental form was invariant under changes of parametrization? Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "arbitrary parametrizations."

Comment: What do you mean by “invariant”? Think what happens if you switch $u$ and $v$. By the way, the general result is just to assume $K=0$ and no planar points.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks!